# jQuery fullcalendar weirdness

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a link connected to a jQuery function that loads (via load() function) a fullcalendar page. But, when I click the link a second time, the fullcalendar layout is all screwy, i.e. the events are all in the wrong place and with single letters displaying in some cases.

Click here to see what I mean:
http://scrapbookcentral.01dev.co.nz/testing/

### Link & jQuery

```
<a id="editCalendarItem" href="##">Edit Calendar Item</a>


$("#editCalendarItem").click(function(e) {
        $("#adminResult").load("/admin/edit_calendar.cfm") // problem
        //window.location.href='/admin/edit_calendar.cfm'; //no problem
        e.preventDefault();
    })
```

### edit_calendar.cfm

```
<link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="/scripts/fullcalendar.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/scripts/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<div id="editcal"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#editcal").fullCalendar({
                aspectRatio: 2,
                buttonText: {
                    today:"Go to Today"
                },
                events:'/components/system.cfc?method=getEditCalendarItem'
            });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: It seems to be working just fine for me in Chrome. I clicked the link way more than two times.

Comment: Did you not notice that the calendar events were misaligned and screwy after the second click? CTRLF5 to reset page. I mean, the events are all in the wrong place and with single letters in some cases. I'm thinking it's a css issue, but not sure why it happens only on subsequent clicks.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing the "coldfusion" tag from this, because as your yourself demonstrate in your posting: it's not a CF issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the remote call is returning the same result each time, so that's not the problem.

I looked at the markup being rendered within the div all the calendar entries are being displayed in, both on first click and on second click.... it has a fair few differences: a lot of heights and widths being very different from one request to the other.  I guess you need to track back through the client-side code and work out where the differences are coming from.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I dig further into that. Appreciate it.